# flickr.people.findByUsername returning "User not found" for valid username

Tags: flickr

I am investigating why the Flickr API is saying that the user "official_omsi" doesn't exist.

I am using the Flickr API Explorer here: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.people.findByUsername

and am looking for the "official_omsi" user, which should be valid looking at this:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/official_omsi

However, the API Explorer is giving: 
{ "stat": "fail", "code": 1, "message": "User not found" }

Any ideas why it is not returning the right user data?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the username is not official_omsi as this may be a short form hence

You need to find the flickr id of this user through [flickr id getter](http://idgettr.com/)

> 72023924@N08

Then you need can use this [API to find the username](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.people.getInfo)

finally find the user name is:

> Oregon Museum of Science and Industry— OMSI